# How to run Jenkins job with a different (remote) xml config file

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Usually jenkins running job with a config file stored in directory:

%Jenkins installation folder%\Jenkins\jobs\%Job name%\config.xml

Is there a possibility to run job using configuration file stored in a different place?

*(For example, we want to use a different configurations for job but do not want to change main config file)*

Answer (score 1):

If the job configs are different, then use different jobs. If you want to "try" some changes without affecting the main job, then copy job and change the copied job.

There is also [**Storable Configs**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Storable+Configs+Plugin) plugin that lets you store different sets of values for Parameterized Build (but this is only for parameterized build values, not the whole job).

And there is [**Job DSL**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) plugin, which allows to load a job config from different files, but it uses it's own language to describe the jobs.